# I need to filter my Order table based on the Conditions table. The catch is that my conditions table can have any number of rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I need to filter my Order table based on the Conditions table. The catch is that my conditions table can have any number of rows.
I have my tables in the below format -

| ConditionSet | BillTo | Shipper | Receiver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | B1, B2 |  |  |
| C2 |  | S1, S3 | R3 |
| C3 | B3, B4 | S3, S4 | R2,R3,R4 |

| OrderNo | BillTo | Shipper | Receiver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B4 | S4 | R4 |
| 2 | B2 | S3 | R2 |
| 3 | B2 | S3 | R1 |
| 4 | B4 | S1 | R3 |
| 5 | B3 | S4 | R1 |
| 6 | B5 | S3 | R3 |
| 7 | B1 | S3 | R5 |
| 8 | B2 | S3 | R6 |
| 9 | B4 | S5 | R6 |
| 10 | B3 | S3 | R2 |

The consitions need to be applied in the following way -

1. For each row in the conditions table - it's an AND condition between the 3 codes.
2. Then we UNION the results of each row

For the above table I have, my results would be -

1. For C1 - 2, 3, 7, 8
2. For C2 - 4, 6
3. For C3 - 10
   Final results - 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10

The equivalent SQL in this case would be -

```
SELECT OrderNo FROM Orders WHERE
(BillTo IN (B1, B2))   OR        --C1
(Shipper IN (S1, S3) AND Receiver IN (R3)) OR     --C2
(BillTo IN (B3, B4) AND Shipper IN (S3, S4) AND Receiver IN (R2, R3, R4))   --C3
```

I need to be able to loop through the conditions table as the number of condition sets can change dynamically.

Can someone please help with the implementation in Power BI?

Tried with PowerBi model and it didn't work.
I am Expecting a solution on how to implement this in PowerBi

Answer (score 0):

If you would take a M code for Table1, this adds a column for matching rows from Table2.  I'm fairly sure your C3 example is wrong since Order1 is also a match

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,", ",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"BillTo", "Shipper", "Receiver"}),
Part1=Table.AddColumn( #"Replaced Value", "Part1", each try Table.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split([BillTo],","),  (x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table2, each Text.Contains([BillTo],x))))[OrderNo] otherwise null),
Part2=Table.AddColumn( Part1, "Part2", each try Table.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split([Shipper],","),  (x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table2, each Text.Contains([Shipper],x))))[OrderNo] otherwise null),
Part3=Table.AddColumn( Part2, "Part3", each try Table.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split([Receiver],","),  (x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table2, each Text.Contains([Receiver],x))))[OrderNo] otherwise null),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Part3, "Matches", each try Table.Combine(List.Transform(List.Intersect(List.RemoveNulls({[Part1],[Part2],[Part3]})),(x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [OrderNo]=x))) otherwise null),
Final=Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Matches])
in  Final
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you're right Order1 is also a match, my bad!
However, I also have a UserID column in my conditions table which I will filter when a user logs in. I use the USERNAME() if embedding the report in an app or USERPRINCIPALNAME() if using PBI Service to pass the Userid. But looks like Power Query doesn't take the USERNAME() expression. Can we write this in DAX or is there any other way?

Comment: Im sure someone can write it in DAX. Im not that conversant in it